# Fetch multiple promises, return only one

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I have a list of urls I wish to fetch. All of these urls returns a json object with a property `valid`. But only one of the fetch promises has the magic `valid` property to `true`.

I have tried various combinations of `url.forEach(...)` and `Promises.all([urls]).then(...)`. Currently my setup is:

```
const urls = [
    'https://testurl.com', 
    'https://anotherurl.com', 
    'https://athirdurl.com' // This is the valid one
];

export function validate(key) {
    var result;
    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        result = fetch(`${url}/${key}/validate`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                if (json.license.valid) {
                    return json;
                } else {
                   Promise.reject(json);
                }
            });
    });

    return result;
}
```

The above is not working because of the async promises. How can I iterate my urls and return when the first `valid == true` is hit?

Comment: So, you are close but are too focused on the fetch/promise.  All you need is one additional deferred that the fetch with valid = true will resolve.

Comment: Do you still want to fire all requests at the same time? Or in an Async series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me throw a nice compact entry into the mix

It uses Promise.all, however every inner Promise will catch any errors and simply resolve to `false` in such a case, therefore Promise.all will never reject - any fetch that completes, but does not have license.valid will also resolve to `false`

The array Promise.all resolves is further processed, filtering out the `false` values, and returning the first (which from the questions description should be the ONLY) valid JSON response

```
const urls = [
    'https://testurl.com', 
    'https://anotherurl.com', 
    'https://athirdurl.com' // This is the valid one
];

export function validate(key) {
    return Promise.all(urls.map(url => 
        fetch(`${url}/${key}/validate`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => json.license && json.license.valid && json)
        .catch(error => false)
    ))
    .then(results => results.filter(result => !!result)[0] || Promise.reject('no matches found'));
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, nice way of using `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's impossible for `validate` to **return** the result ([see here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)). But it can return a *promise* for the result.

What you want is **similar** to [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), but not quite the same (`Promise.race` would reject if one of the `fetch` promises rejected prior to another one resolving with `valid = true`). So just create a promise and resolve it when you get the first resolution with `valid` being true:

```
export function validate(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let completed = 0;
        const total = urls.length;
        urls.forEach(url => {
            fetch(`${url}/${key}/validate`)
                .then((response) => {
                    const json = response.json();
                    if (json.license.valid) {
                        resolve(json);
                    } else {
                        if (++completed === total) {
                            // None of them had valid = true
                            reject();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    if (++completed === total) {
                        // None of them had valid = true
                        reject();
                    }
                });
        });
    });
}
```

Note the handling for the failing case.

Note that it's possible to factor out those two `completed` checks if you like:

```
export function validate(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let completed = 0;
        const total = urls.length;
        urls.forEach(url => {
            fetch(`${url}/${key}/validate`)
                .then((response) => {
                    const json = response.json();
                    if (json.license.valid) {
                        resolve(json);
                    }
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    // Do nothing, converts to a resolution with `undefined`
                })
                .then(() => {
                    // Because of the above, effectively a "finally" (which we
                    // may get on Promises at some point)
                    if (++completed === total) {
                        // None of them had valid = true.
                        // Note that we come here even if we've already
                        // resolved the promise -- but that's okay(ish), a
                        // promise's resolution can't be changed after it's
                        // settled, so this would be a no-op in that case
                        reject();
                    }
                });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This looks "promising". I'll test it out, and let you know! :-)

Comment: One comment, I run into "undefined is not an object". Going to debug it a bit further. :-)

Comment: @janhartmann: Is it possible for the data not to have a `license` property? If so, you'll need `if (json.license && json.license.valid)`. (We also really shouldn't be calling that variable `json`; it's not JSON at that point.)

Comment: Nope, all have the same `json.license.valid`.

Comment: `response.json()` returns a Promise - so, this wont work - and is the cause of the error most likely

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [SynJS](https://github.com/amaksr/SynJS). Here is a working example:

```
var SynJS = require('synjs');
var fetchUrl = require('fetch').fetchUrl;

function fetch(context,url) {
    console.log('fetching started:', url);
    var result = {};
    fetchUrl(url, function(error, meta, body){
        result.done = true;
        result.body = body;
        result.finalUrl = meta.finalUrl; 
        console.log('fetching finished:', url);
        SynJS.resume(context);
    } );

    return result;
}

function myFetches(modules, urls) {
    for(var i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
        var res = modules.fetch(_synjsContext, urls[i]);
        SynJS.wait(res.done);
        if(res.finalUrl.indexOf('github')>=0) {
            console.log('found correct one!', urls[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
};

var modules = {
        SynJS:  SynJS,
        fetch:  fetch,
};

const urls = [
              'http://www.google.com', 
              'http://www.yahoo.com', 
              'http://www.github.com', // This is the valid one
              'http://www.wikipedia.com'
          ];

SynJS.run(myFetches,null,modules,urls,function () {
    console.log('done');
});
```

It would produce following output:

```
fetching started: http://www.google.com
fetching finished: http://www.google.com
fetching started: http://www.yahoo.com
fetching finished: http://www.yahoo.com
fetching started: http://www.github.com
fetching finished: http://www.github.com
found correct one! http://www.github.com
done
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid the fact of testing each URL, you can use the following code.

```js
const urls = [
    'https://testurl.com', 
    'https://anotherurl.com', 
    'https://athirdurl.com' // This is the valid one
];

export function validate(key) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  function testUrl(url) {
     fetch(`${url}/${key}/validate`)
       .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
         if (json.license.valid) {
            resolve(json);
           return;
          }
          if (urlIndex === urls.length) {
            reject("No matches found...");
            return;
          }
          testUrl(urls[urlIndex++]);
        });
    }

  let urlIndex = 0;
    if (!urls.length)
     return reject("No urls to test...");
    testUrl(urls[urlIndex++]);
  });
}
```

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer.

Comment: I don't agree with you. You use `forEach`, so you will iterate over all elements even if the first url returns `valid == true`